# Syntax error in one of my included modules when pushed to BlueMix

Tags: javascript, node.js, ibm-cloud

I have a node.js application which leverages the watson_developer_cloud.

The application works fine when I run it locally, but wen I deploy it to BlueMix it tells me that there are Syntax errors in the watson libraries. Initially it was complaining about "illegal use of const in strict mode", but then I changed the start command to "node --harmony app.js".

Now the error is:

```
  2017-08-15T11:36:31.73+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR /home/vcap/app/node_modules/watson-developer-cloud/language-translation/v2.js:109
   2017-08-15T11:36:31.73+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   for (const type in inputTypes) {
   2017-08-15T11:36:31.73+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR                   ^^
   2017-08-15T11:36:31.73+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR SyntaxError: Unexpected token in
   2017-08-15T11:36:31.73+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
   2017-08-15T11:36:31.73+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
   2017-08-15T11:36:31.73+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
   2017-08-15T11:36:31.73+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
   2017-08-15T11:36:31.73+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
   2017-08-15T11:36:31.73+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at require (module.js:380:17)
   2017-08-15T11:36:31.73+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/watson-developer-cloud/index.js:37:33)
   2017-08-15T11:36:31.73+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
   2017-08-15T11:36:31.73+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
   2017-08-15T11:36:31.73+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

Any ideas about how I can solve this? (as I said it works fine locally)

Comment: What node version is BlueMix running? Try using 'strict mode'

Comment: It's currently 6.11.1 as a default but is configurable in the "engines" section of package.json.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tip.

My package.json specified a node version of  "0.10.x" in the engines section (it was an old sample I inherited). When I edited it to 6.11.1 it started to work fine.